# SQL Server create centroid of a polygon inside of a polygon

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, geospatial, spatial-query, centroid

I would like to create a centroid of a polygon (type geometry) such that the centroid falls inside of the polygon

I have tried with function shape.STCentroid() which is creating the centroid but for my shape/polygon the centroid is falling outside of the polygon

Spatial result centroid is falling outside of the polygon as polygon is a '<' shaped polygon and centroid looks like '<.'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only require the point to be in the polygon you can use [STPointOnSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stpointonsurface-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), which will always be in the polygon. If you want a "good" point you may want to look into the pole of inaccessibility, see this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285537/using-polygon-centroids-tool-points-arent-always-inside-polygon-can-i-fix-th) for more details.